# I can't install discord.py on an ubuntu server (digital ocean)

Tags: ubuntu, discord.py, digital-ocean

I'm following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-discord-bot-in-python-on-ubuntu-20-04) (updated February 2021) to host my bot on Digital Ocean. The point is that when I have to install python3 along with discord.py it gives me this error.

```
root@LMIIBot:~# mkdir ~/.venvs
root@LMIIBot:~# python3 -m venv ~/.venvs/discord
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/root/.venvs/discord/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

in the guide is the [second step](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-discord-bot-in-python-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-creating-a-python-virtual-environment-for-your-project).

Edit:i did the recommended command but it tells me it is outdated, what should i write?

```
root@LMIIBot:~# apt-get install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: The error pretty much tells you what to do

Comment: i did that command but it tells me it is outdated

Comment: Is there any reason you're creating the venv? My suggestion would be to simply not create it if you have problems with it

Comment: I'm not very experienced at the host level and I was following the guide that advised me to create it. It's the only guide I've found for discord.py (the rest all discord.js)

Comment: Maybe you should first [read about virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), though I don't think you really need them in a host, I'd skip that step

Comment: ok I will inquire. However I need it because at the moment I use heroku and it limits me by making me restart my bot every day

Comment: I tried but it gives me the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I simply did not have python installed perfectly, for those who happen to have the same problem as me follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-20-04-server) (for those who have ubuntu 20.04)